# How to create a list of widgets?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, listview

MyApp uses **ListView** to display a list of theaters and restaurants using **ListTiles** which are written in many places with little alteration.

How to refactor these boilerplate pieces of code?
It would be nice to store all the text in a separate file and transmit it somehow.

```
/*----------------------main.dart----------------------*/

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './my_list_tile.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter layout demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter layout demo'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: const [
            MyListTile(
                title: 'CineArts at the Empire',
                subtitle: '85 W Portal Ave',
                icon: Icons.theaters),
            MyListTile(
                title: 'The Castro Theater',
                subtitle: '429 Castro St',
                icon: Icons.theaters),
            MyListTile(
                title: 'Alamo Drafthouse Cinema',
                subtitle: '2550 Mission St',
                icon: Icons.theaters),
            MyListTile(
                title: 'Roxie Theater',
                subtitle: '3117 16th St',
                icon: Icons.theaters),
            MyListTile(
                title: 'United Artists Stonestown Twin',
                subtitle: '501 Buckingham Way',
                icon: Icons.theaters),
            MyListTile(
                title: 'AMC Metreon 16',
                subtitle: '135 4th St #3000',
                icon: Icons.theaters),
            Divider(),
            MyListTile(
                title: 'K\'s Kitchen',
                subtitle: '757 Monterey Blvd',
                icon: Icons.restaurant),
            MyListTile(
                title: 'Emmy\'s Restaurant',
                subtitle: '1923 Ocean Ave',
                icon: Icons.restaurant),
            MyListTile(
                title: 'Chaiya Thai Restaurant',
                subtitle: '272 Claremont Blvd',
                icon: Icons.restaurant),
            MyListTile(
                title: 'La Ciccia',
                subtitle: '291 30th St',
                icon: Icons.restaurant),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[the app itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32moy.png)

Comment: Check ListView.builder or ListView.seperated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Create a model class to store and manage widget information.**

```dart
class DataModel {
  final String? title;
  final String? subTitle;
  final IconData? icon;

  const DataModel({this.title, this.subTitle, this.icon});
}
```

**Then you can make a list of data model like:**

```dart
 final List<DataModel> data = const [
    DataModel(
      title: 'CineArts at the Empire',
      subtitle: '85 W Portal Ave',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'The Castro Theater',
      subtitle: '429 Castro St',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'Alamo Drafthouse Cinema',
      subtitle: '2550 Mission St',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'Roxie Theater',
      subtitle: '3117 16th St',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'United Artists Stonestown Twin',
      subtitle: '501 Buckingham Way',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'AMC Metreon 16',
      subtitle: '135 4th St #3000',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'K\'s Kitchen',
      subtitle: '757 Monterey Blvd',
      icon: Icons.restaurant,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'Emmy\'s Restaurant',
      subtitle: '1923 Ocean Ave',
      icon: Icons.restaurant,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'Chaiya Thai Restaurant',
      subtitle: '272 Claremont Blvd',
      icon: Icons.restaurant,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'La Ciccia',
      subtitle: '291 30th St',
      icon: Icons.restaurant,
    ),
  ];
```

And convert your `ListView` to `ListView.builder`, then return your `MyListTile` with data's "index" item:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyListTile(
    title: data[index].title,
    subtitle: data[index].subtitle,
    icon: data[index].icon
  ),
),
```

#### Full Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DataModel {
  final String? title;
  final String? subtitle;
  final IconData? icon;

  const DataModel({this.title, this.subtitle, this.icon});
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<DataModel> data = const [
    DataModel(
      title: 'CineArts at the Empire',
      subtitle: '85 W Portal Ave',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'The Castro Theater',
      subtitle: '429 Castro St',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'Alamo Drafthouse Cinema',
      subtitle: '2550 Mission St',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'Roxie Theater',
      subtitle: '3117 16th St',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'United Artists Stonestown Twin',
      subtitle: '501 Buckingham Way',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'AMC Metreon 16',
      subtitle: '135 4th St #3000',
      icon: Icons.theaters,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'K\'s Kitchen',
      subtitle: '757 Monterey Blvd',
      icon: Icons.restaurant,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'Emmy\'s Restaurant',
      subtitle: '1923 Ocean Ave',
      icon: Icons.restaurant,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'Chaiya Thai Restaurant',
      subtitle: '272 Claremont Blvd',
      icon: Icons.restaurant,
    ),
    DataModel(
      title: 'La Ciccia',
      subtitle: '291 30th St',
      icon: Icons.restaurant,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter layout demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter layout demo'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.length,
          // You should pass model to your "MyListTile" directly, instead of passing like that:
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyListTile(
            title: data[index].title,
            subtitle: data[index].subtitle,
            icon: data[index].icon,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```